# Getting unexpected time with AM instead PM and viceversa after getting Timestamp column from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I have a column in my table with timestamp datatype and the value for instance look like '2014-08-30 00:00:50'. From database point of view I know it's showing the time of 12:00:50 AM for '00:00:50' and  12:00:50 PM if the value is 2014-03-30 12:00:50. 
But When I process the data in my application by fetching the table values, I'm getting **AM** for the time which has to be **PM**. I want to know how could I achieve this? I also want to know that the problem weather it is from my application side ? or database side? Could I achieve this If I get time from database as unixtimestamp format?
I've seen several questions related to this but I found none of them led me to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: How you are fetching the data from db, SQL query required. Are you doing any kind of post-processing on the returned data. If yes what is it done related to this timestamp column?

Comment: We need some samples of how you are retrieving your data, as its most likely a formatting issue.

Comment: @Duncan I doubt its related to insertion, as OP already says what database column is showing is right. AM/PM switch happens when queried from db.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj yeah I already edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the date as a string you can do the following to convert it to AM/PM.

```
    String s = "2014-08-30 00:00:50";
    SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("y-MM-dd H:mm:s");
    Date in24HrFormat = d.parse(s);
    String in12HrFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("y-MM-dd h:mm:sa").format(in24HrFormat);
    System.out.println(in12HrFormat);
```